# NGINX - 404 Not Found Error - after updating my server

Tags: nginx

I issued the following commands to my Debian Server **apt-get update**, and then **apt-get upgrade**, after which whenever I visit my site (fundlined.com) it returns a **NGINX 404 Not Found Error**. It's probably caused due to certain files being over written.

I tried to search for any overwritten code, but can't seem to find any.

What changes should I make, in order to fix this issue?

Comment: Are there other sites on this server which are responding? Anything in the Nginx logs? Any chance the upgrade changed where Nginx is looking for its configuration files (and thus caused it to "lose" your site files)?

Comment: The URL of the site is fundlined.com. It's hosted on a single server, and any fundlined.com link I try to open returns a NGINX 404 Error.

I went through NGINX conf, and everything seemed to be in place.

Comment: OK, so Nginx is most likely getting all requests to the IP and responding regardless of whether it knows it's supposed to be fundlined.com. Is there anything in its logs? *This is a key debugging step.* Can you verify that it's reading the configuration files you think it is (perhaps by making a visible change and restarting)?

Comment: Also, this is information which should be in your question - we shouldn't be debugging step-by-step in the comments.

Comment: Yes, I understand - this is my first time here :) I looked at the NGINX Error Logs, found a critical error, googled a fix - and then finally fixed it. The site is back online. Thank You :)

The Error: Connect() to unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock failed

Comment: Awesome. If you get a chance, you're allowed to answer your own questions here - if you can write up how you fixed it and post it as an answer it may help future searchers.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced this issue.

After checking virtual host file as to where the right error and access log were, I found that it runs on `fast-cfi` not `php5-fpm` which conflicts after upgrade. So I removed `php5-fpm`, stopped it and started `fastci`.